# Get continuous package name in service

Tags: android, android-launcher, package-name

I want to get continuously package name of launch app its working fine but when no one apps open then i want to get default launcher package name,So launcher package name get like below code:

```
PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launcher_pkgname = localPackageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).activityInfo.packageName;
```

Its working fine but in some device when i directly press home key then its get last open app package name not launcher package name
what can i do?
Help me please